# Android nested layout

Tags: android, layout

I am developing my first Android app. Although I have 15 years of Java software development experience, Android is new to me. My desired look is a background image with other images on top of it, as well as labels and phone numbers. It seems like the best way to accomplish this is a Linear Layout for the background image, with a nested layout for the other fields on top of that. I have searched online and cannot find any sample code on how to accomplish this. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to develop? If you are you using Eclipse with the Android SDK this is super easy. Put the desired picture in the appropriate drawable folder, go to the graphical view of layout that corresponds to your activity, on the right side of the screen there is a list of all the properties, find background, then select your picture from drawables. You can also do this from the xml using android:background="@drawable/yourPic". This way you don't have to worry about having things layered on top of it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I have struggled trying to figure this out. Thanks again for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go through followings:

**1.** http://phandroid.com/2011/05/11/10-tips-for-android-ui-design/

**2.** http://mobile.tutsplus.com/series/android-user-interface-design/

**3.** http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/

**4.** http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/thinking-like-web-designer.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will check them out.

Answer (score 0):

If I got, something like this can work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<stuff>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <stuff>

    </RelativeLayout>

<stuff>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I used it in an app, and made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[image]First of all, `RelativeLayout` is the best layout to use. It depends on your design.
If your design says to keep all the views either vertically OR horizontally, you can use `LinearLayouts` in between.
My suggested way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout1" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_parent" 
android:orientation="Horizontal">

<View1 />
<View2 />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout2" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_parent" 
android:orientation="Vertical" 
android:layout_below="@id/layout1">

<View3 />
<View4 />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which will yield you something like this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. RelativeLayout seems a little tricky. I was considering GridLayout because I have a design that is a little complex. Thoughts?

Comment: I prefer not to use `GridLayout` unless you need to display something in Matrix format. Using `RelativeLayout` you can place the `Views` based on each others positions.